# Kubuntu 15.04: Cannot Install Language Support (Language Selector Gnome)

Tags: software-center, kubuntu, language-support

I use Kubuntu 15.04. I have tried couple of times to install language selector Gnome, but it didn't work. I tried to use synaptic and Ubuntu software center. At the end of the installation process, it seems that the software is installed, but I cannot find it in my computer. I also tried to install it using the terminal, the same result.

Can somebody help me?

Update:
I decided not to install the language selector. I just did what Gunnar suggested me to do. And it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubuntu isn't really compatible with Language Support. Probably you can start it from a terminal window:

```
gnome-language-selector
```

but I doubt it would be a good idea to try to use it for controlling display language or regional formats. Kubuntu uses KDE stuff for the purpose instead.

What's the purpose for wanting to install/use it?

*Edit:*

From a comment I understand that the goal is to make sure that the language packs and related language support packages get completely installed. That can be done in a terminal window by running this command:

```
sudo apt-get install $(check-language-support)
```

Comment: I have tried with the terminal. It doesn't work. I want to install it because I think the language packs are not installed properly during the installation of the OS. It causes the thesaurus in Libreoffice not active. I had the same problem before with Ubuntu Gnome. Solving it, I installed the language support (language selector), and reinstalled the language packs, then thesaurus works.  I want to do the same with Kubuntu, but it seems that installing language support is difficult. By the way I'm glad if you can suggest me a solution aside of installing language selector.

Comment: @herrysusanto: Just added a solution by editing the answer. (It still sounds strange that language-selector-gnome cannot be installed, but - as already said - it doesn't really matter.)